# Changing from windows-latest to ubuntu-latest causes nuget package compatibility issues

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-pipelines

My team recently moved away from using service fabric and instead are using linux docker containers.

All runs fine locally, but when I went to create my pr in VSTS I got an error saying **Your docker server host is configured for 'windows', however the docker-compose project targets 'linux'**

Ok, so I thought the fix for this might be updating my azure-pipeline.yml file so that vmImage gets switched from

```
vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

to

```
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

First, I'm unsure if this is the proper approach.  If it is, the problem I'm having once I save and create a new PR for this update is all of my nuget packages are coming back saying they aren't compatible with .net 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

This issue probably was caused by an old version of Nuget being used in the ubuntu-latest agent.

You can try using nuget 5.x version in the agent by adding the [NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline. See below:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x
```

Check out this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64848744/cant-build-net-5-in-pipeline) for more information.

Comment: So I added this in with no luck.  Same error.  Still saying all of my nuget packages are not compatible.  Thank you tho

Comment: @CBC_NS What is the task you are using to build the project?