# Azure Devops Build failing for .Net 5 when using multiple frameworks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-5, dotnetcorecli

I have a project that builds using the following frameworks:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

This compiles just fine on my local machine, but when I push it to Azure, it fails.

When I have the following in my YAML file:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  platform: x64

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Then I get:

> ##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5):
> Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0
> were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
> (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your
> application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

And if I try

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build all'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true
```

I get:

> ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5):
> Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0
> were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
> (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your
> application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

1. The developer packs documentation refer only to the older .Net Framework, so I suspect this is irrelevant/outdated.
2. This works fine if I change .Net 5 for .Net Core 3.1, i.e. `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: Maybe duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842484/azure-devops-compatibility-problems-moving-from-net-core-3-1-to-net-5-at-nug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your project doesn't build successfully is because the Microsoft-Hosted agent doesn't have the.NET 5.0 SDK installed.

You can download the.NET 5.0 SDK using [Use.NET Core Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops):

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
inputs:
packageType: 'sdk'
Version: '{version}'
includePreviewVersions: {true/false}
```

This task can download a specific version of the .Net SDK from the network and add it to the PATH.

In addition, since you are using multiple versions of .NET in your project, you can use this task to specify which version of.NET you will use in the following tasks.

In other words, this task has two functions:

1. Download a specific SDK version that is not installed.
2. Specify which SDK version will be used for the following tasks.

Comment: Same issue happening for me as well. seems to be they have update agents with .NET 5 recently. due to that build failing.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with build agent machines.

If you use ***cloud azure*** devops you need to wait when they will update their build machines.

If you use on ***premise azure*** devops try to update build machines by yourself.

Comment: It's the cloud azure.  Seems strange to me.  There's been quite a fanfare regarding the full release of .Net 5 and I'd have thought the (cloud) Azure agents would be updated in conjunction with this.  If not before....it was supposedly "production ready" when RC2 was release.....

Comment: Posted on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1258239/azure-devops-build-failing-for-net-5-when-using-mu.html (feel free to up-vote if you're experiencing this too)